# What is the correct way of doing Django imports ?

Tags: python, django

I would like to understand if the there is a correct and accepted way of handling imports in Django?

I use following patterns >

```
# import views from Django app called xxx to urls.py in the same app
from . import views
```

What I see been used in many tutorials and blogs >

```
# import views from Django app called xxx to urls.py in the same app
from xxx import views
```

Similarly I use >

```
# import YYY and XXX from xxx.models to xxx.serializers.py
from .models import YYY, XXX
```

What I see been used for example in Django-Rest-Framework tutorial is >

```
# import YYY and XXX from xxx.models to xxx.serializers.py
from xxx.models import XXX, YYY
```

Doing imports in the way shown in tutorials does not work in my Django apps. Am I doing something wrong? I picked my way from Django documentation. 
I am using Django 1.10 with Python3.5

Comment: Please share your project tree structure. Just install tree module and run `tree` command from your project directory and add the output in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a Django Project which looks like this: 2 apps named `app_1` and `app_2`

```
mysite/
    manage.py
    app_1/
        __init__.py
        models.py
        views.py
    app_2/
        __init__.py
        models.py
        views.py
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
```

Now to run this application you will use this command.

`mysite> python manage.py runserver`

Here you are running the command from `mysite` parent folder/directory.

Now in a python `app_1` views code say you are import `app_2` model (which you should not have to do if your code is well structured). But to make that import you will have to do the complete namespace.

example:

`from app_2.models import XXX`

On the other hand if you wanted to import model from within the same app `app_1` you could have used

`from .models import YYY`

but if you are running the program using `mysite> python manage.py runserver` command you should be able to import the same module with the full namespace path also.

`from app_1.models import YYY`

NOTE: A good way to code is always be explicit. Hence you would notice these are more commonly prescribed.

```
# import views from Django app called xxx to urls.py in the same app
from xxx import views

# import YYY and XXX from xxx.models to xxx.serializers.py
from xxx.models import XXX, YYY
```